# Is it bad etiquette to knock on a potential supervisor's door if he hasn't responded to my email?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor, interview, lab-meeting

I'm a Master's student at Cambridge, and I emailed a potential supervisor for PhD a while ago. He replied that he was interested to proceed further and asked about my funding details. I informed him that I have already applied for PhD at the university and have already applied for funding. He didnt respond after that, and I had sent him four reminders. His research interests align with mine and would it be rude to show up at his office and request for a review given that he is in the same university?

Comment: Does he have posted office hours?

Comment: He hasnt posted any. I called up his assistant, but she doesnt have access to his calender either. The deadline to make an application is in a week, so I wanted to ask him about the projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a scheduling need to get information then, by all means, knock. Apologize for any interruption and ask for a brief meeting, then or soon.

He is probably busy. He is probably willing to accommodate you if you have a need. I would consider it more courteous to knock than to make a phone call, actually.

Need driven interruptions can be forgiven. Don't overthink it.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: And if he yells at you blame a weird internet guy named Buffy ;-). And, if he keeps yelling, tell him that this weird guy had more than 30 years experience in academia.

Comment: Hahaha! I sure will!

Comment: I just met him and he was happy to see me! he also made an appointment to meet up with me and discuss.